# Сравнение двух массивов в php(для select)

Tags: php, массивы, циклы, foreach

[image: Первый массив]

[image: Второй массив]

[image: Форма поиска]

Есть два массива. Как правильно сравнить эти два массива и если permission_id(первого массива) == id(второго массива), то в форме select(multiple) их сделать selected, а остальное просто оставить в этой форме (в select). Пробовал по всякому, но не доходит дело до конца.
Вот пробный код (не работает).

```
<select name="type_bus[]" id="type_bus" multiple class="form-control select2me" data-placeholder="Выберите тип">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?foreach($getPerm as $row){?>
                        <?foreach($permBrunch as $item){?>
                            <?if(array_search($item['permission_id'], $row)){?>
                                <option selected value="<?=$item['permission_id']?>"><?=$item['name']?></option>
                            <?} else {?>
                                <option value="<?=$item['permission_id']?>"><?=$item['name']?></option>
                            <?}?>
                        <?}?>
                    <?}?>
                </select>
```

Comment: Я так понимаю - ключ массива: на основе чего соотносить , это `name` ?

Comment: Нет, там есть id. permission_id(первого массива) == id(второго массива) - это одно и тоже. Вот это соотносить и надо

Comment: нет, permission_id это явно не ключ - так как во втором массиве напримаер он может быть 1 для пункта Добавить приказ. То есть 1 или 3 - не указывает на `Добавить приказ`. Вы понимаете то насчёт ключа, или нет? В первом массиве у вас список категорий, а во втором списке (видимо это категории конкретной статьи) - единственная связь с первым списком это `name`

Answer (score 0):

Если первый массив у вас имеет название $getPerm, а второй массив имеет название $permBrunch, тогда можно так:

```
<select name="type_bus[]" id="type_bus" multiple class="form-control select2me" data-placeholder="Выберите тип">
    <option value=""></option>
    <? foreach($getPerm as $row):
        foreach($permBrunch as $item):
            $selected = ($row['permission_id'] == $item['id'])?'selected ':''; ?>
                <option <?=$selected?>value="<?=$row['permission_id']?>"><?=$item['name']?></option>
    <? endforeach; endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

---

Попробуйте выполнить следующий код, возможно это то, что вам нужно.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#dynamicAttributes').select2({
    allowClear: true,
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    width: 500
  });

  $("select").on("select2:select", function(evt) {
    var element = evt.params.data.element;
    var $element = $(element);
    $element.detach();
    $(this).append($element);
    $(this).trigger("change");
  });

});
```

```css
.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
  display: none;
}


/* line 1, ../scss/core.scss */

.select2-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* line 1, ../scss/_single.scss */

.select2-container .select2-selection--single {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 38px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}


/* line 12, ../scss/_single.scss */

.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/* line 25, ../scss/_single.scss */

.select2-container[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}


/* line 1, ../scss/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}


/* line 12, ../scss/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 8px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/* line 21, ../scss/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container .select2-search--inline {
  float: left;
}


/* line 24, ../scss/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}


/* line 31, ../scss/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


/* line 1, ../scss/_dropdown.scss */

.select2-dropdown {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1051;
}


/* line 18, ../scss/_dropdown.scss */

.select2-results {
  display: block;
}


/* line 22, ../scss/_dropdown.scss */

.select2-results__options {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* line 28, ../scss/_dropdown.scss */

.select2-results__option {
  padding: 6px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}


/* line 34, ../scss/_dropdown.scss */

.select2-results__option[aria-selected] {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* line 39, ../scss/_dropdown.scss */

.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown {
  left: 0;
}


/* line 43, ../scss/_dropdown.scss */

.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown--above {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}


/* line 49, ../scss/_dropdown.scss */

.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown--below {
  border-top: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}


/* line 55, ../scss/_dropdown.scss */

.select2-search--dropdown {
  display: block;
  padding: 7px;
}


/* line 59, ../scss/_dropdown.scss */

.select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field {
  padding: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* line 64, ../scss/_dropdown.scss */

.select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


/* line 69, ../scss/_dropdown.scss */

.select2-search--dropdown.select2-search--hide {
  display: none;
}


/* line 15, ../scss/core.scss */

.select2-close-mask {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #fff;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}


/* line 1, ../scss/theme/default/_single.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 2px;
}


/* line 6, ../scss/theme/default/_single.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single:focus {
  outline: 0;
}


/* line 10, ../scss/theme/default/_single.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
  color: #444;
  line-height: 34px;
}


/* line 15, ../scss/theme/default/_single.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* line 21, ../scss/theme/default/_single.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__placeholder {
  color: #999;
}


/* line 25, ../scss/theme/default/_single.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
  height: 36px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  width: 20px;
}


/* line 35, ../scss/theme/default/_single.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b {
  border-color: #888 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 4px 0 4px;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 0;
}


/* line 56, ../scss/theme/default/_single.scss */

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
  float: left;
}


/* line 60, ../scss/theme/default/_single.scss */

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
  left: 1px;
  right: auto;
}


/* line 68, ../scss/theme/default/_single.scss */

.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--single {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: default;
}


/* line 72, ../scss/theme/default/_single.scss */

.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
  display: none;
}


/* line 81, ../scss/theme/default/_single.scss */

.select2-container--default.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b {
  border-color: transparent transparent #888 transparent;
  border-width: 0 4px 5px 4px;
}


/* line 1, ../scss/theme/default/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: text;
  height: 22px;
}


/* line 7, ../scss/theme/default/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none !important;
  padding: 0 0 0 4px !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 100%;
}


/* line 15, ../scss/theme/default/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__placeholder {
  color: #999;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: left;
}


/* line 23, ../scss/theme/default/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__clear {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}


/* line 31, ../scss/theme/default/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #4a89dc;
  // border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: default;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 1px 2px 2px !important;
}


/* line 46, ../scss/theme/default/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 2px;
}


/* line 55, ../scss/theme/default/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove:hover {
  color: #333;
}


/* line 63, ../scss/theme/default/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice,
.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__placeholder {
  float: right;
}


/* line 67, ../scss/theme/default/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* line 72, ../scss/theme/default/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove {
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* line 80, ../scss/theme/default/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  outline: 0;
}


/* line 87, ../scss/theme/default/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--multiple {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: default;
}


/* line 92, ../scss/theme/default/_multiple.scss */

.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection__choice__remove {
  display: none;
}


/* line 6, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--single,
.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--multiple {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}


/* line 13, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--single,
.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--multiple {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}


/* line 20, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}


/* line 22, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field:focus {
  outline: 0;
}


/* line 29, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
}


/* line 36, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-results>.select2-results__options {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 2px !important;
}


/* line 42, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[role=group] {
  padding: 0;
}


/* line 46, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] {
  color: #999;
}


/* line 50, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
  background-color: #EEE;
}


/* line 54, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
  padding-left: 1em;
}


/* line 57, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__group {
  padding-left: 0;
}


/* line 61, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
  margin-left: -1em;
  padding-left: 2em;
}


/* line 65, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
  margin-left: -2em;
  padding-left: 3em;
}


/* line 69, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
  margin-left: -3em;
  padding-left: 4em;
}


/* line 73, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
  margin-left: -4em;
  padding-left: 5em;
}


/* line 77, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
  margin-left: -5em;
  padding-left: 6em;
}


/* line 88, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected] {
  background-color: #4a89dc;
  color: white;
}


/* line 93, ../scss/theme/default/layout.scss */

.select2-container--default .select2-results__group {
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>

<select id="dynamicAttributes" style="display:none" multiple="multiple">
 <option selected value="internal_notes_container">Добавить статью</option>
 <option value="event_attributes_container">Добавить приказ</option>
 <option value="sell_attributes_container">Скачать приказ</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Он выводит еще и ненужную информацию. То есть элементы, которые selected, они также находятся в форме поиска select. Мне нужно же так: те элементы, которые selected, они не попадали в форму. У меня сейчас так и происходит. Но дело в том, что если удаляешь их из формы (снимаешь атрибут selected), то информация начинает дублироваться. Потому что на уровне php эта информация не обновилась. Так как он находится и в том массиве, и в том.

Comment: Так и должно быть - это особенность работы select2me. Если вы уберете выбор какого-то элемента, то он должен быть в поиске. Но если элемент выбран, и если его отметить второй раз, то снимется выделение элемента. Посмотрите исходный код страницы (html), там будет все правильно.

Comment: Не знал. Ну со стороны пользователя то глупо выглядит. Тогда нужно искать другое решение. Спасибо) Но вот все равно как-то неправильно, что мы видим эти элементы выбраны и они находятся в списках. Пользователю это вообще не подойдет. Думал, что есть решение.

Comment: Могу подтвердить ваши слова. Пару раз вставлял select2 в уже готовые проекты, в качестве "хорошего улучшения интерфейса", и получал много вопросов со стороны пользователей - для них это казалось непривычным и неудобным.

Comment: Добавил решение на JS, так можно добиться решения вашей задачи. Можете выполнить код и посмотреть результат работы